# Configuring ArcGIS Online Map Template

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, configurable-map-viewer

I'm creating a configured template to host to ArcGIS Online.  I started from the Finder app, and configured simple things like the color scheme.  My only problem is that the Share button isn't working.  I haven't even touched that part of the script, so I don't know what's going wrong.  The button shows up, but when I click it, nothing happens. I'm not very good at scripting.  (I deleted a lot of the code, so it would fit below)

```
"values": {
    "webmap": "d3df161ab8204e848b359d5f352b5b65",
    "titleBar.title": "Title",
    "titleBar.iconUrl": "images/onlineapp.png",
    "colorizer.theme": "Green",
    "searchBox.hint": "",
    "featureSearcher.searchLayersString": "[]",
    "featureSearcher.displayLayersString": "[]",
    "highlighter.showFeaturePopup": true,
    "highlighter.highlightZoomLevel": 16,
    "basemapBox.basemapgroupTitle": "",
    "basemapBox.basemapgroupOwner": "",
    "helpMessageBox.content": ""
},

"configurationSettings": [{
    "category": "<b>Header</b>",
    "fields": [{
        "label": "Title",
        "fieldName": "titleBar.title",
        "type": "string",
        "tooltip": "Application title displayed in header"
    }, {
        "label": "Icon URL",
        "fieldName": "titleBar.iconUrl",
        "type": "string",
        "tooltip": "Icon in top left corner of application. Icon should be 48px high."
{
    "category": "<b>Find Settings</b>",
    "fields": [{
        "label": "Hint",
        "fieldName": "searchBox.hint",
        "type": "string",
        "tooltip": "Search hint (e.g. Find a Parcel, Find a Park)"
    }, 
    "category": "<b>Application Help</b>",
    "fields": [{
        "label": "Help Text",
        "fieldName": "helpMessageBox.content",
        "type": "string",
        "stringFieldOption": "textarea",
        "tooltip": "Help text displayed to the end users of this application"
    }]
}],

"ui": [{
    "classname": "js.LGNotes",
    "config": {
        "notes": [
            "@@@commit@@@"
        ]
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGColorizer",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "colorizer",
        "parentDiv": "contentDiv",
        "colorTable": [{
            "theme": "NeutralGrays",
            "colors": ["#969696", "#fff", "#464646", "#d8d8d8"]
        }, {
            "theme": "EarthBrowns",
            "colors": ["#be9969", "#fff", "#523b20", "#d8d8d8"]
        }, {
            "theme": "SeaBlues",
            "colors": ["#00b9f2", "#fff", "#004575", "#d8d8d8"]
        }, {
            "theme": "NaturalGreens",
            "colors": ["#aad04b", "#fff", "#2a7f33", "#d8d8d8"]
        }, {
            "theme": "WarmBrights",
            "colors": ["#f89927", "#fff", "#da4d1e", "#d8d8d8"]
        }, {
            "theme": "green",
            "colors": ["#137d79", "#fff", "#898989", "#d8d8d8"]
        }]
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGFrame",
    "styles": ".appFrame{width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;position:absolute}.frameHeader{width:100%;height:48px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;border:1px solid lightgray}.frameContent{width:100%;padding:0px;position:absolute}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "outerFrame",
        "headerDivId": "headerFrame",
        "contentDivId": "contentFrame",
        "parentDiv": "contentDiv",
        "rootClass": "appFrame",
        "headerDivClass": "frameHeader",
        "contentDivClass": "frameContent"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGBusy",
    "styles": ".busyImage{display:none;background-image:url('images/loading.gif');width:80px;height:17px;position:absolute;z-index:100}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "busyIndicator",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "horizOffset": 0,
        "vertOffset": 0,
        "busyImageClass": "busyImage"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGMap",
    "styles": ".mapContainer{margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute}.simpleInfoWindow .close{width:32px!important;height:32px!important;background-size:32px 32px;left:244px!important;top:-18px!important}.simpleInfoWindow .title{min-height:14px}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "map",
        "rootClass": "mapContainer",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "fill": true
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGHighlighter",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "highlighter",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "dependencyId": "map",
        "lineHiliteColor": "#0000ff",
        "fillHiliteColor": [0, 0, 255, 0.1]
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGTitleBar",
    "styles": ".appTitleBar{height:40px;margin:0px;padding:2px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute}.titleIcon{height:44px;margin:-4px;padding:0px;float:left}.titleText{height:48px;margin:3px 3px 3px 12px;padding:0px;font-size:200%;vertical-align:middle;word-wrap:break-word;float:left}@media all and (max-width: 520px){.titleText{display:none}}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "titleBar",
        "parentDiv": "headerFrame",
        "rootClass": "appTitleBar",
        "horizOffset": 4,
        "vertOffset": 0,
        "iconClass": "titleIcon",
        "titleClass": "titleText"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGMapDijitContainer",
    "styles": ".dijitContainer{position:absolute;z-index:35;}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "homeButton",
        "parentDiv": "map",
        "dependencyId": "map",
        "rootClass": "dijitContainer",
        "horizOffset": 19,
        "vertOffset": 91,
        "dijitAmd": "esri/dijit/HomeButton"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGMapDijitContainer",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "locateButton",
        "parentDiv": "map",
        "dependencyId": "map",
        "rootClass": "dijitContainer",
        "horizOffset": 19,
        "vertOffset": 132,
        "dijitAmd": "esri/dijit/LocateButton"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGGallery",
    "styles": ".commandPanel{height:44px;margin:-3px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}.commandPanel table{border-spacing:0px}.commandPanelArrow{width:12px;height:48px;margin:4px;padding:0px;cursor:pointer;vertical-align:middle}.okIE .commandPanelArrow{border-radius:4px}.commandButton{width:44px;height:44px;text-align:center;cursor:pointer}.okIE .commandButton{border-radius:8px}.commandTextButton{width:100%;height:44px;cursor:pointer}.okIE .commandTextButton{border-radius:8px}.commandText{display:inline;height:32px;margin-left:2px;font-size:120%;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom}.okIE .commandText{display:inline-block}.commandIcon{width:32px;height:32px;margin-top:6px}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "commandPanel",
        "parentDiv": "headerFrame",
        "rootClass": "commandPanel",
        "horizOffset": -4,
        "vertOffset": 0,
        "itemClass": "commandPanelItem",
        "arrowClass": "commandPanelArrow"
    }
    }, {
"classname": "js.LGSearchAddress",
"config": {
    "rootId": "addressSearcher",
    "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
    "dependencyId": "map",
    "searchUrl": "http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer",
    "addressParamName": "SingleLine",
    "minimumScore": 80,
    "validLocators": ["USA.StreetName", "USA.PointAddress", "USA.StreetAddress"],
    "outWkid": 102100,
    "outFields": ["Loc_name", "Match_addr"]
}
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGLaunchUrl",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "launcher",
        "sameWinTrigger": "launch/parent",
        "newWinTrigger": "launch/blank"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGPrintMap",
    "styles": ".absolute{position:absolute}.printMapBox{display:none;width:269px;padding:4px;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;z-index:40;word-wrap:break-word;border:1px solid lightgray}.printFormatsPanel{height:52px;margin:0px;padding:2px;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}.pushbuttonOn{border:1px solid blue}.printDlogItem{margin:3px!important}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "printMap",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "rootClass": "printMapBox",
        "horizOffset": -2,
        "vertOffset": 2,
        "asynchronous": false,
        "format": "PDF",
        "preserveScale": true,
        "title": "",
        "author": "",
        "orientationButtonClass": "commandButton printDlogItem",
        "orientationButtonIconClass": "commandIcon",
        "landscapeButtonIconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 31 27 0-18-5 0 0-5-25 0 0 23z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'M 31 9 27 4'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 28 13-25 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 28 15-25 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 13 17-10 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "landscapeButtonTooltip": "@tooltips.landscape",
        "landscapeServerSpec": "Letter ANSI A Landscape",
        "portraitButtonIconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 5 1 18 0 0 5 5 0 0 25-23 0z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 23 1 5 5'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 9 19 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 16 19 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 13 10 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 11 19 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 18 15 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "portraitButtonTooltip": "@tooltips.portrait",
        "portraitServerSpec": "Letter ANSI A Portrait",
        "titleHint": null,
        "titleHintDefault": "@labels.title",
        "titleClass": "printDlogItem",
        "authorHint": null,
        "authorHintDefault": "@labels.author",
        "authorClass": "printDlogItem",
        "printButtonIconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 1c 6 0 12 0 19 0 0 3 0 6 0 9-6 0-12 0-19 0 0-3 0-6 0-9z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 19c 6 0 12 0 19 0 0 4 0 8 0 12-6 0-12 0-19 0 0-4 0-8 0-12z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'circle','cx':27,'cy':14,'r':1},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 6 10c-2 0-4-1-5 1 0 2 0 3 0 5 0 3 0 6 0 9 1 1 3 0 5 0l 0 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 26 10c 2 0 4-1 5 1 0 2 0 3 0 5 0 3 0 6 0 9-1 1-3 0-5 0l 0 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 10 22c 4 0 9 0 13 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 10 27c 4 0 9 0 13 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 10 24c 4 0 7 0 11 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "printButtonClass": "commandButton printDlogItem",
        "printButtonIconClass": "commandIcon",
        "printButtonTooltip": "@tooltips.print",
        "iconColorizerId": "colorizer",
        "copyrightText": null,
        "dependencyId": "map",
        "trigger": "print",
        "publishReady": "printingReady",
        "publishWorking": "printing",
        "publishPrintUrl": "printUrl"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGFetchPrintedMap",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "fetchPrintedMap",
        "publish": "launch/blank",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "dependencyId": "map",
        "trigger": "printingReady",
        "triggerPrintUrl": "printUrl",
        "publishPrintAvailable": "printAvailable",
        "publishPrintNotAvailable": "printNotAvailable",
        "printAvailabilityTimeoutMinutes": 15
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGMessageBox",
    "styles": ".helpMessageBox{display:none;max-width:400px;max-height:300px;padding:16px;position:absolute;overflow:auto;z-index:40;word-wrap:break-word;border:1px solid lightgray}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "helpMessageBox",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "rootClass": "helpMessageBox",
        "horizOffset": -2,
        "vertOffset": [2, -2],
        "trigger": "help"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGSelfHidingMessageBox",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "printingNotificationMessageBox",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "rootClass": "helpMessageBox",
        "content": "!widgets.print.NLS_printing",
        "timeoutSeconds": 5,
        "horizOffset": -2,
        "vertOffset": 2,
        "trigger": "printing"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGPublishEcho",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "diagMessageBox",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "rootClass": "helpMessageBox",
        "horizOffset": -2,
        "vertOffset": [2, -2],
        "trigger": "error"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGBasemapBox",
    "styles": ".basemapBox{display:none;width:280px;max-height:244px;padding:4px;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;z-index:40;word-wrap:break-word;border:1px solid lightgray}.basemapGallery{width:96%;height:96%;padding:4px;overflow-y:auto;}.lt-ie9 .basemapGallery{height:220px}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "basemapBox",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "rootClass": "basemapBox",
        "galleryClass": "basemapGallery",
        "horizOffset": -2,
        "vertOffset": [2, -2],
        "trigger": "basemap",
        "dependencyId": "map"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGMapBasedMenuBox",
    "styles": ".shareBox{display:none;width:140px;text-align:center;padding:4px;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;z-index:40;word-wrap:break-word;border:1px solid lightgray}.shareCmdTextButton{width:44px;height:44px;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "shareBox",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "rootClass": "shareBox",
        "horizOffset": -2,
        "vertOffset": 2,
        "trigger": "share",
        "dependencyId": "map"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGSearchBoxByText",
    "styles": ".searchBox{display:none;width:200px;max-height:224px;padding:4px;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;z-index:40;word-wrap:break-word;border:1px solid lightgray}.resultsListBox{top:53px;overflow:auto}.okIE .resultsListBox{position:absolute;left:4px;right:4px;bottom:4px;width:auto}.lt-ie9 .resultsListBox{width:100%;height:182px}.resultsListTable{width:97%;margin:4px}.lt-ie9 .resultsListTable{width:87%}.resultsListBody{width:80%}.resultsListSearching{background-image:url('images/loading.gif');background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;width:100%;height:1.5em}.resultsListEntry{width:84%;margin:2px;padding:4px;cursor:pointer}",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "searchBox",
        "trigger": "search",
        "publish": "showFeature",
        "parentDiv": "contentFrame",
        "rootClass": "searchBox",
        "horizOffset": -2,
        "vertOffset": [2, -2],
        "searcher": "addressSearcher",
        "showPrompt": "@tooltips.search",
        "resultsListBoxClass": "resultsListBox",
        "resultsListTableClass": "resultsListTable",
        "resultsListBodyClass": "resultsListBody",
        "resultsListSearchingClass": "resultsListSearching",
        "resultsListEntryClass": "resultsListEntry"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGCommand",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "search",
        "tooltip": "@tooltips.search",
        "iconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'circle','cx':13,'cy':13,'r':10},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':255,'g':255,'b':255,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'line','x1':20,'y1':20,'x2':30,'y2':30},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':255,'g':255,'b':255,'a':0.25},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "iconColorizerId": "colorizer",
        "parentDiv": "commandPanel",
        "rootClass": "commandButton",
        "iconClass": "commandIcon",
        "dependencyId": "addressSearcher",
        "publish": "search"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGCommand",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "basemap",
        "tooltip": "@tooltips.basemap",
        "iconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'rect','x':2,'y':2,'width':12,'height':12,'r':0},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'rect','x':18,'y':2,'width':12,'height':12,'r':0},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'rect','x':2,'y':18,'width':12,'height':12,'r':0},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'rect','x':18,'y':18,'width':12,'height':12,'r':0},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "iconColorizerId": "colorizer",
        "parentDiv": "commandPanel",
        "rootClass": "commandButton",
        "iconClass": "commandIcon",
        "dependencyId": "basemapBox",
        "publish": "basemap"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGCommand",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "share",
        "tooltip": "@tooltips.share",
        "iconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'M 16 2L 2 2 2 30 30 30 30 16'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'M 22 2L 30 2 30 10'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'M 30 2L 16 16'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "iconColorizerId": "colorizer",
        "parentDiv": "commandPanel",
        "rootClass": "commandButton",
        "iconClass": "commandIcon",
        "dependencyId": "shareBox",
        "publish": "share"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGCommand",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "shareEmail",
        "tooltip": "@tooltips.shareViaEmail",
        "iconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 2 5 28 0 1 1 0 3L 16 16 1 8 1 6zm-1 7 0 15L 31 27 31 12 16 19 1 12'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "iconColorizerId": "colorizer",
        "parentDiv": "shareBox",
        "rootClass": "shareCmdTextButton",
        "iconClass": "commandIcon",
        "publish": "share/email"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGCommand",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "shareFB",
        "tooltip": "@tooltips.shareViaFacebook",
        "iconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'M 18 31V 17h 5l 1-5H 18V 9c 0-2 0-3 3-3l 3 0V 1C 23 1 22 1 20 1 16 1 13 3 13 8V 12H 8v 5h 5V 31h 5z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "iconColorizerId": "colorizer",
        "parentDiv": "shareBox",
        "rootClass": "shareCmdTextButton",
        "iconClass": "commandIcon",
        "publish": "share/facebook"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGCommand",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "shareTw",
        "tooltip": "@tooltips.shareViaTwitter",
        "iconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'M 31 7C 30 7 29 8 27 8 29 7 30 6 30 4 29 5 28 5 26 6 25 5 24 4 22 4c-3 0-6 3-6 6 0 0 0 1 0 1C 11 11 6 9 3 5 3 6 2 7 2 8c 0 2 1 4 3 5-1 0-2 0-3-1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 5 5 6-1 0-1 0-2 0 0 0-1 0-1 0 1 2 3 4 6 4-2 2-5 3-8 3 0 0-1 0-1 0 3 2 6 3 9 3 11 0 18-9 18-18 0 0 0-1 0-1 1-1 2-2 3-3z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "iconColorizerId": "colorizer",
        "parentDiv": "shareBox",
        "rootClass": "shareCmdTextButton",
        "iconClass": "commandIcon",
        "publish": "share/twitter"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGCommandToggle",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "print",
        "tooltip": "@tooltips.print",
        "iconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 1c 6 0 12 0 19 0 0 3 0 6 0 9-6 0-12 0-19 0 0-3 0-6 0-9z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 19c 6 0 12 0 19 0 0 4 0 8 0 12-6 0-12 0-19 0 0-4 0-8 0-12z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'circle','cx':27,'cy':14,'r':1},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 6 10c-2 0-4-1-5 1 0 2 0 3 0 5 0 3 0 6 0 9 1 1 3 0 5 0l 0 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 26 10c 2 0 4-1 5 1 0 2 0 3 0 5 0 3 0 6 0 9-1 1-3 0-5 0l 0 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 10 22c 4 0 9 0 13 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 10 27c 4 0 9 0 13 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 10 24c 4 0 7 0 11 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "iconDisabledJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 7 19c 6 0 12 0 19 0 0 4 0 8 0 12-6 0-12 0-19 0 0-4 0-8 0-12z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'circle','cx':27,'cy':14,'r':1},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 6 10c-2 0-4-1-5 1 0 2 0 3 0 5 0 3 0 6 0 9 1 1 3 0 5 0l 0 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 26 10c 2 0 4-1 5 1 0 2 0 3 0 5 0 3 0 6 0 9-1 1-3 0-5 0l 0 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 10 22c 4 0 9 0 13 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 10 27c 4 0 9 0 13 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 10 24c 4 0 7 0 11 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'circle','cx':16,'cy':9,'r':7},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 16 4 0 6'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 16 10 5 0'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':1,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "iconColorizerId": "colorizer",
        "parentDiv": "commandPanel",
        "rootClass": "commandButton",
        "iconClass": "commandIcon",
        "publish": "print",
        "dependencyId": "printMap",
        "triggerEnable": "printingReady",
        "triggerDisable": "printing",
        "isVisible": false,
        "isEnabled": true
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGCommand",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "help",
        "tooltip": "@tooltips.help",
        "iconJson": "[{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'M 31 16C 31 24 24 32 15 31 8 31 1 24 1 17 1 10 5 4 11 2c 6-2 13 0 17 5 2 3 3 6 3 9z'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'path','path':'m 13 12c 0-3 4-4 6-2 2 2 0 4-1 6-1 1-2 2-1 4'},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}},{'shape':{'type':'circle','cx':17,'cy':23,'r':0.5},'stroke':{'type':'stroke','color':{'r':0,'g':0,'b':0,'a':1},'style':'solid','width':2,'cap':'butt','join':4}}]",
        "iconColorizerId": "colorizer",
        "parentDiv": "commandPanel",
        "rootClass": "commandButton",
        "iconClass": "commandIcon",
        "publish": "help"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGShareAppExtents",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "shareAppExtEmail",
        "trigger": "share/email",
        "publish": "launch/parent",
        "subject": ".titleBar.title",
        "tinyURLServiceURL": "",
        "tinyURLResponseAttribute": "data.url",
        "shareUrl": "mailto:%20?subject=${subject}&body=${http://ssm.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Solutions/s2.html?appid=386909e9d38140948cf011bbad91d0a9}",
        "busyIndicator": "busyIndicator",
        "dependencyId": "map"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGShareAppExtents",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "shareAppExtFB",
        "trigger": "share/facebook",
        "publish": "launch/blank",
        "subject": ".titleBar.title",
        "tinyURLServiceURL": "",
        "tinyURLResponseAttribute": "data.url",
        "shareUrl": "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=${url}&t=${subject}",
        "busyIndicator": "busyIndicator",
        "dependencyId": "map"
    }
}, {
    "classname": "js.LGShareAppExtents",
    "config": {
        "rootId": "shareAppExtTw",
        "trigger": "share/twitter",
        "publish": "launch/blank",
        "subject": ".titleBar.title",
        "tinyURLServiceURL": "",
        "tinyURLResponseAttribute": "data.url",
        "shareUrl": "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=${url}&text=${subject}",
        "busyIndicator": "busyIndicator",
        "dependencyId": "map"
    }
}]
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I am assuming you have downloaded [this template](https://github.com/Esri/local-government-online-apps) from GitHub. I just downloaded it and the share functionality worked as expected out of the box. I am running it locally using the following URL (as documented in the README.md file):

http://localhost/finder/s2.html?app=apps2/Finder

I think your best bet would to use some sort of source control (such as TFS or GitHub), and compare the initial code base to your code base. Then you can work out what is breaking the sharing functionality.

Also is there a particular reason you want to host it yourself? Why not use the ArcGIS Online version?

Comment: I do want to use the ArcGIS Online version. I just want to tweak it a little. I did end up finding a work around. I ended up embedding my finder app into a story map (which has the share options).  Because of this, I was able to delete the "share button" on my Finder app and use the ones in the story map.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to parse your JSON-config file? You can parse it over here: http://json.parser.online.fr/ and it'll return errors in a clean way.

Have you tried debugging your page with the debug-console open? For Google Chrome you can read the documentation over here: 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en#opening-the-console

The last one is always a great help for me as I am a Arcgis javascript developer too and need to debug sites quite often.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to configure the template without JSON. You can go to your web map and edit the data, under the edit tool, click manage. Choose what layer you want to configure templates for and then for each value, choose the dropdown menu > properties and set up the individual templates. I edited the definition service (my JSON was perfect) and AGOL had some bugs with the templates. I would definitely do it this way when working with cloud hosted services.